# How to display multiple marker in google maps with the maker has its own info windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I want to display multiple marker in google maps with the maker has its own info windows. The problem is when I click either of the marker only one info windows will come out(the info windows for the marker that I click not display).And one more problem is when the info window come out, it not smooth(there is like a box white box at the back also appeared)

[image]

```js
// map center
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(2.855262784366583, 105.4302978515625);

// marker position
//var factory = new google.maps.LatLng(2.855262784366583, 105.4302978515625);

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: center,
    zoom: 7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

  };

         // Create a <script> tag and set the USGS URL as the source.
         var script = document.createElement('script');
         // This example uses a local copy of the GeoJSON stored at
         // http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_week.geojsonp
         script.src = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/json/earthquake_GeoJSONP.js';
         document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapOptions);

  // Loop through the results array and place a marker for each
     // set of coordinates.
     window.eqfeed_callback = function(results) {
       for (var i = 0; i < results.features.length; i++) {
         var coords = results.features[i].geometry.coordinates;
         var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[1],coords[0]);
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: latLng,
           map: map
         });



         // InfoWindow content
         var content = '<div id="iw-container">' +
                           '<div class="iw-title">Porcelain Factory of Vista Alegre</div>' +
                           '<div class="iw-content">' +
                             '<div class="iw-subTitle">History</div>' +
                             '<img src="http://maps.marnoto.com/en/5wayscustomizeinfowindow/images/vistalegre.jpg" alt="Porcelain Factory of Vista Alegre" height="115" width="83">' +
                             '<p>Founded in 1824, the Porcelain Factory of Vista Alegre was the first industrial unit dedicated to porcelain production in Portugal. For the foundation and success of this risky industrial development was crucial the spirit of persistence of its founder, José Ferreira Pinto Basto. Leading figure in Portuguese society of the nineteenth century farm owner, daring dealer, wisely incorporated the liberal ideas of the century, having become "the first example of free enterprise" in Portugal.</p>' +
                             '<div class="iw-subTitle">Contacts</div>' +
                             '<p>VISTA ALEGRE ATLANTIS, SA<br>3830-292 Ílhavo - Portugal<br>'+
                             '<br>Phone. +351 234 320 600<br>e-mail: geral@vaa.pt<br>www: www.myvistaalegre.com</p>'+
                           '</div>' +
                           '<div class="iw-bottom-gradient"></div>' +
                         '</div>';

         // A new Info Window is created and set content
         var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
           content: content,

           // Assign a maximum value for the width of the infowindow allows
           // greater control over the various content elements
           maxWidth: 350
         });

         // marker options
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: latLng,
           map: map,
           title:"Porcelain Factory of Vista Alegre"
         });

         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: latLng,
           map: map,
           title:"Porcelain Factory of Vista Alegre"
         });



         // This event expects a click on a marker
         // When this event is fired the Info Window is opened.
         google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
           infowindow.open(map,marker);
         });

         // Event that closes the Info Window with a click on the map
         google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
           infowindow.close();
         });

         // *
         // START INFOWINDOW CUSTOMIZE.
         // The google.maps.event.addListener() event expects
         // the creation of the infowindow HTML structure 'domready'
         // and before the opening of the infowindow, defined styles are applied.
         // *
         google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {

           // Reference to the DIV that wraps the bottom of infowindow
           var iwOuter = $('.gm-style-iw');

           /* Since this div is in a position prior to .gm-div style-iw.
            * We use jQuery and create a iwBackground variable,
            * and took advantage of the existing reference .gm-style-iw for the previous div with .prev().
           */
           var iwBackground = iwOuter.prev();

           // Removes background shadow DIV
           iwBackground.children(':nth-child(2)').css({'display' : 'none'});

           // Removes white background DIV
           iwBackground.children(':nth-child(4)').css({'display' : 'none'});

           // Moves the infowindow 115px to the right.
           iwOuter.parent().parent().css({left: '115px'});

           // Moves the shadow of the arrow 76px to the left margin.
           iwBackground.children(':nth-child(1)').attr('style', function(i,s){ return s + 'left: 76px !important;'});

           // Moves the arrow 76px to the left margin.
           iwBackground.children(':nth-child(3)').attr('style', function(i,s){ return s + 'left: 76px !important;'});

           // Changes the desired tail shadow color.
           iwBackground.children(':nth-child(3)').find('div').children().css({'box-shadow': 'rgba(72, 181, 233, 0.6) 0px 1px 6px', 'z-index' : '1'});

           // Reference to the div that groups the close button elements.
           var iwCloseBtn = iwOuter.next();

           // Apply the desired effect to the close button
           iwCloseBtn.css({opacity: '1', right: '38px', top: '3px', border: '7px solid #48b5e9', 'border-radius': '13px', 'box-shadow': '0 0 5px #3990B9'});

           // If the content of infowindow not exceed the set maximum height, then the gradient is removed.
           if($('.iw-content').height() < 140){
             $('.iw-bottom-gradient').css({display: 'none'});
           }

           // The API automatically applies 0.7 opacity to the button after the mouseout event. This function reverses this event to the desired value.
           iwCloseBtn.mouseout(function(){
             $(this).css({opacity: '1'});
           });
         });
       }
     }


}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
#map-canvas {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 400px;
 max-width: none;
}
#map-canvas img {
 max-width: none !important;
}
.gm-style-iw {
 width: 350px !important;
 top: 15px !important;
 left: 0px !important;
 background-color: #fff;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(178, 178, 178, 0.6);
 border: 1px solid rgba(72, 181, 233, 0.6);
 border-radius: 2px 2px 10px 10px;
}
#iw-container {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#iw-container .iw-title {
 font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
 font-size: 22px;
 font-weight: 400;
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: #48b5e9;
 color: white;
 margin: 0;
 border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
}
#iw-container .iw-content {
 font-size: 13px;
 line-height: 18px;
 font-weight: 400;
 margin-right: 1px;
 padding: 15px 5px 20px 15px;
 max-height: 140px;
 overflow-y: auto;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}
.iw-content img {
 float: right;
 margin: 0 5px 5px 10px; 
}
.iw-subTitle {
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 700;
 padding: 5px 0;
}
.iw-bottom-gradient {
 position: absolute;
 width: 326px;
 height: 25px;
 bottom: 10px;
 right: 18px;
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>5 ways to customize the Google Maps infowindow</title>



      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


</head>

<body>

  <body>
  <div id="map-canvas"/>
</body>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDcTisThxNuI0ALuP04klCDK2nqetNKb0w&callback=initMap">
</script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script  src="js/index.js"></script>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your issue is a common problem with multiple markers initialized in a loop.  One example of a fix using function closure is in the duplicate: [Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example).

Answer (score 1):

Simplest fix for your code.  Change:

```
 // This event expects a click on a marker
 // When this event is fired the Info Window is opened.
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
   infowindow.open(map,marker);
 });
```

To:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
   infowindow.open(map,this);
 });
```

The `this` in the marker click function is the marker.

That will make the InfoWindow open on the clicked marker.  But as far as I can tell all the InfoWindows have the same content, which isn't very useful.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/qaz0o5Lt/1/)